Rails Console not Loading in Cloud 9
I am having an issue with loading the Rails console on my Cloud 9 IDE. When I try to load it I do see one error concerning a missing keyword in the console.rb, It is the first line after the load starts. Then it just goes on through until it hits rails:4:in and then I just go back to the terminal prompt. No other errors and no console prompt.
Below is the log of what happens when I invoke rails console:
ubuntu:~/environment/toy_app (main) $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4)
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debug-1.5.0/lib/debug/console.rb:25:in `reset': missing keyword: :encoding (ArgumentError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline.rb:311:in `inner_readline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline.rb:258:in `block (2 levels) in readmultiline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline/io/ansi.rb:149:in `block in with_raw_input'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline/io/ansi.rb:149:in `raw'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline/io/ansi.rb:149:in `with_raw_input'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline.rb:257:in `block in readmultiline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline.rb:252:in `synchronize'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/reline-0.5.11/lib/reline.rb:252:in `readmultiline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `readmultiline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb/input-method.rb:468:in `gets'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1075:in `block in read_input'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1363:in `signal_status'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1073:in `read_input'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1095:in `readmultiline'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1120:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1119:in `loop'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1119:in `each_top_level_statement'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1042:in `eval_input'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1023:in `block in run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1022:in `catch'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:1022:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/irb-1.14.1/lib/irb.rb:905:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/thor-1.3.2/lib/thor.rb:538:in `dispatch'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ubuntu:~/environment/toy_app (main) $ 


debug gem is out of date.

That fixed it. Thanks!! Updated Debug Gem to 1.9.2 and console loads fine now.

The debug gem is bundled with Ruby 2.7+ so you do not need to list it in your Gemfile. https://stdgems.org/3.1.2/

@max i think that only applies to default gems, bundled gems need to be in the Gemfile.

@Alex no, default gems are parts of the standard library but extracted out into gems. Bundled gems are not part of the standard library but are shipped together with Ruby. Otherwise they would just be normal gems. You can list them in the gemfile if you want a different version but it's not actually required. https://nts.strzibny.name/ruby-stdlib-default-bundled-gems/

@max that article says "Bundled gems ... As with other 3rd-party gems, you have to include them into gemspec or gemfile.". I definitely can't require "debug" if it is not in the gemfile.
